# ESLint Unexpected Parsing error with Atom & React Native

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, eslint

While playing around with a simple react-native setup, I suddenly stumbled upon some (maybe not so) weird ESLint stuff.

Here is my Javascript file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {
  const { textStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={textStyle}>App Header!</Text>
    <View/>
  );
};
const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20
  }
};
export default Header;
```

The issue comes as the following ESLint error in `textStyle: {` line:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}" (Fatal)
```

I have installed latest `linter` (v2.2.0) and `linter-eslint` (v8.4.1) packages in `Atom`.

I am using a predefined set of rules from the `npm` package `rally-coding` that I have installed as a dev dependency in the project, and here's my `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
  "extends": "rallycoding",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  }
}
```

Any ideas where this might be coming from? None of the workarounds suggested in the (many) Github issues threads helped so far.

Comment: `<View/>` should be `</View>`

Comment: @bennygenel well spotted, thanks. This allegedly linter sent me each other way around and actually prevented me from spotting the real error location earlier. I mean seriously...

Comment: @bennygenel That should be the answer though, if you could transform it into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error is caused by a not closed `View` tag.

`<View/>` should be `</View>`

**Side note:** linter is not always really accurate with these sort of errors. A small suggestion is that always check if you closed all your tags if you had a `expected "}"` error and already checked all your `}`